# Partial incremental merge update on dbt with snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have an incremental dbt model and want to selectively update only specific columns based on logic.

Eg: Table 1 (Destination)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |

Table 2 (Source)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |

I would only like to update 1st row and 1st column of the destination table to value from source(1) based on some logic and keep everything else the same in the row.

I tried using `is_incremental()` macro for incremental merges and `incremental_predicates` but could not achieve the desired result as the update would happen to the whole row and not specific columns.
`merge_update_columns` only allows the same column updates every time. In my case it could be different columns that need to be updated for every run based on logic and present values.

Comment: I am assuming you can't wrap the update logic in a IF(TRUE, DO LOGIC, ELSE KEEP) with your existing SQL? i.e. you use a Full Drop style table to recalculate your values on every iteration?

The only alternative I can think requires you to write a custom macro to see if you can identify the columns you want to update ahead of time, and then resolve the DML for a MERGE directly via the macro